# is there something wrong with my nested structure declaration?

Tags: c, nested, structure, nested-forms

So when typing calls to the nexted structure variables in the structure declared below, it appears to look normal, but the compiler keeps throwing me weird errors. Any idea what could be wrong with the declaration?

```
 struct makeFileSets {
       char target[50];                     // array of targets
       char sources[80][50];                    // an array of sources
       char commands[80][50];                   // an array of command lines (non seperated)
       int sourcesTag;                          // current number of sources
       int commandsTag;                     // current number of command lines
       struct commandLineSets {
           int makeFileNum;             // represets an index for the makefile they corresond to
           int numVariables;                // the # of variables
           int numOptions;                  // the # of options
           int numCommands;             // the # of commands
           char variables[80][50];          // represents variables in each command line
           char options[20][20];            // represents option tags in each command line
           char commands[80][50];           // represents the commands from the command line
        } myCommands[50];
   };
```

Comment: Those "weird errors" tell you what the compiler thinks is wrong.  They'd probably tell us, too, if you included them.  :P

Comment: The question is tagged `c` and comments are `c++`-style. Being more specific about weird errors indeed may help.

Comment: 1. Show the errors. 2. Your struct is huge, one instance of it takes almost half MB. If you allocate it on stack, it can be a problem

Comment: im aware of what an error is. i was simply saying that the compiler simply "cuts" out. by isolating sections of my program and testing when it 'likes', i have come to the conclusion is that this is section of code giving me issues.

Comment: note that you must access the nested struct not using makeFileSet::commandLineSet, but using commandLineSet, in C. it has no struct scope.

Comment: @user1770173, do you think you made it any more clear now?

Comment: @user1770173: Seriously...are we supposed to *just guess* what error messages you're getting?  Cause most of us aren't in the mood to play psychic today.  Those error messages *mean* something, and if you'd bother to tell us, we could probably interpret them for you.

Comment: it shoots me an 'unhandled exception' which is something i do not know how to deal with, nor describe. also, microsoft compilers suppert single line comments (preceded by '//') in c programming. obviously the code itself is much longer, but working with the code, it would seem this is where the error is. i wasn't asking if there was an error with the code, simply if there was an issue with the declaration of the struct here.

Comment: *Compiler* is not in habit of throwing unhandled exceptions unless it's broken. If your code does, then most likely, for the reason @icepack mentioned.

Comment: i just feel like being 20 years back. c has // comments, right?

Comment: @Johannes: Pretty sure C99 does, and VC++ does as well.

Comment: You should [edit] and add *exactly what error messages you are getting*.  You can flag and request reopening after doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Theres no problem with that struct.

Comment: I can confirm this on [codepad.org](http://www.codepad.org): http://codepad.org/dNnn3wPt

Comment: Well, +1. After all this is correct answer to the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your initializing commands[] twice.

Comment: Are you sure? He's using `commands` and `myCommands` as variable names.

Comment: Where?  The "second" declaration is inside the nested struct, which should be fine.

Comment: Ah, thankyou. Still new to it all. How do I comment instead of provide an answer?

Comment: @Nick I think you can't comment yet, your rep count is too small. Answer other questions and your reputation will grow ;)

Comment: that is true! thats actually a mistake on my part! thanks!

Comment: @user1770173 **NO Nick was wrong! That's not the error!** See my link commented on dreamcrash's answer: the code (struct) is working!

Comment: I don't think he's saying that's the error, but that it was a mistake and he appreciates the point out either way. But rep me if I dun good ;)